# Межстраничное объявление InterstitialAd показывается всего один раз

Tags: android, admob

Есть межстраничное объявление:

```
//Создаём межстраничное объявление
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-****/****");
// Создаём запрос к AdMob
AdRequest adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
// Начинаем загружать объявление
interstitial.loadAd(adRequesti);

public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        displayInterstitial();
    }
```

Проблема в том,что реклама показывается всего один раз.Хотелось бы, чтобы реклама показывалась всегда при попадании на это активити.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто сразу после показа загрузите рекламу ещё раз:

```
public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();

        // Создаём запрос к AdMob
        AdRequest adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        // Начинаем загружать объявление
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequesti);
    }
}
```